# Entry in PTE is physical or virtual address? | Virtual Memory

Tags: virtual-memory

I know that the each entry in last level of page tables hold a physical address in memory.

As per my understanding the intermediate page tables hold a physical addresses in their entries. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily: the last level may be over a virtual machine, and hence mapped on a physical page by an hypervisor, that may in turn have several address levels.

There is no conceptually predefined limit to the number of "floors" than can be built under or over a given one.

And everything you call "floor" can be called "ceiling" by who lives in the apartment below the one you live.

Of course, there must be a basement. But it's placement is not necessarily known to the level that "runs" you code.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of processor. Some use physical addresses for page table entries while other use virtual address (allowing paging of the table) for some tables and physical addresses for others.

Note that there must be some set of page table entries using physical addresses or you get the chicken and egg problem.